# Why using ">=" does not work in the following example why must we use "-1" instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am just learning and practicing Javascript as well as javascript libraries. In this example, I am working with JQuery. This example is just a simple quote rotator(changer whatever you want to call it). The code works fine. My issue is with the if statement in the anonymous function(within the fadeOut method). the argument within the if statement is:

```
currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1
```

why does it have to be written like that instead of

```
currentQuote >= allQuotes.length
```

shouldn't using greater than or equal to work exactly the same way? And if not, why not? The entire code follows below.

//HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="quote-holder">
    <blockquote>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
     Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</body>
```

//CSS

```
.quote-holder {
  width: 30%;
}

blockquote {
  display: none;
}

blockquote:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

//javascript Jquery

```
let allQuotes = $("blockquote");
let currentQuote = 0;

function changeQuote(){
  $(allQuotes[currentQuote]).fadeOut(200, function(){if(currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1){
    currentQuote = 0;
  }else {
    currentQuote++;
  }
    $(allQuotes[currentQuote]).fadeIn(200)});


}

let quoteTimer = setInterval(changeQuote, 3000)
```

Comment: I think you need to put some parentheses in? `currentQuote == (allQuotes.length - 1)`

Comment: `currentQuote >= allQuotes.length` evaluates to false if `currentQuote  = allQuotes.length - 1` where `currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1` evaluates to true.

Comment: `currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1` means that `currentQuote` is *less* than `allQuotes.length`. `currentQuote >= allQuotes.length` means that `currentQuote` is *more* than or *equal* to `allQuotes.length`. It can't be both more than and less than at the same time.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Uhm.  No.  `currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1` means that `currentQuote` is one less than allQuotes.length.  It's an important distinction given the context of the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the loop **needs to reset** whenever the array position is reaching to the end. Otherwise it will always show the first position.

If the array length is 5. the positions are [0],[1],[2],[3],[4] so **4** is the last element which is the:

`array.length - 1.`

In the function of your question you need to set the position to **0** so you can have the loop of quotes keep rotating. I exlpained more in steps with comments.

```js
let allQuotes = $("blockquote");
let currentQuote = 0;

function changeQuote(){
  $(allQuotes[currentQuote]).fadeOut(200, function(){
  if(currentQuote == allQuotes.length - 1){ //if last position
    currentQuote = 0; //reset
  }else { //else 
    currentQuote++; // go next
  }
    $(allQuotes[currentQuote]).fadeIn(200)});


}

let quoteTimer = setInterval(changeQuote, 3000)
```

```css
.quote-holder {
  width: 30%;
}

blockquote {
  display: none;
}

blockquote:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="quote-holder">
    <blockquote>
      Hello 
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
     How are you? 
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      Good Thanks 
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</body>
```